# Can 'as' be used instead of 'such as' or 'like'?

Tags: grammaticality

Examples:

*I love big dogs, **as** German Shepherd and Labrador*

*I can play quite a few musical instruments, **as** the flute, the guitar, and the piano.*

They sound wrong to me, but I don't know the grammatical reason why. Can you clarify this?

PS: if there's difference between BE and AE on this, please point it out.

Comment: You need *such as*. Note that the dog names should be pluralised. Edit: *like* is also good.

Comment: Related to http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19370/formal-alternative-for-like-and-such-as and http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15092/synonym-for-such-as

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As http://www.vault.com/blog/admit-one-vaults-mba-law-school-and-college-blog/fine-tune-your-grammar-likely-like-vs-such-as-vs-asas-ifas-though says:

> Use like before a noun or pronoun. Use as before a clause, adverb or
>   prepositional phrase. Use as if and as though before a clause. Like is
>   generally used as a preposition in such a context. As is generally
>   used as a conjunction of manner while sometimes serving as a
>   preposition with the meaning of "in the capacity of". As you can tell,
>   the focus of the comparison shifts from the noun when used with like
>   to the verb when used with as, as if, or as though.

- My mother's cheesecake tastes **like** glue.
- I love frozen pizza because there is no other snack **like** it.
- My mother's cheesecake tastes great, **as** a mother's cheesecake should.
- There are times, **as** now, that learning grammar becomes important.
- He golfed well again, **as** in the tournament last year.
- He served **as** captain in the navy.
- He often told half-truths, **as** any politician would.
- He looks **as if** he knows me.
- It looked **as if** a storm were on the way.
- He yelled at me **as though** it were my fault.
- He behaves **like** a child.
- He behaves **as if** he were a child.
- **Like** his brother, he plays chess.
- **As** I told you, they have well-mannered children.
- He works **as** a window cleaner.
- **As** President, he was very popular.
- **As** I was playing football, I met my best friend.
- I love sciences, **like** physics.

Some animals, such as lions can be dangerous.

As she's contagious, she won't go to school.

> In sum, on the GMAT, use like before a noun or pronoun when
>   emphasizing similar characteristics between two persons, groups or
>   things. Use such as before a noun or phrase when introducing examples.

- **Correct**: I enjoy playing musical instruments **such as** piano and violin.
- **Wrong**: I enjoy playing musical instruments **like** piano and violin.

In your examples you should use either **"such as"** to introducing examples of objects or **"like"** to show similar characteristics and similarity.

- I love big dogs **such as** a German Shepherd and a Labrador. - means you love a German Shepherd and a Labrador.
- I love big dogs **like** a German Shepherd and a Labrador. - means you love big dogs that resemble a German Shepherd and a Labrador altogether.

> Notice the usage of the conjunction **"and"** and also notice the
>   **comma** that isn't at all necessary there.

- I can play quite a few musical instruments **such as** the flute, the guitar, and the piano.
- I can play quite a few musical instruments **like** the flute, the guitar, and the piano.

The difference is identical to that mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Yes because the **such** is used as an indicator for multiple examples. The same goes with **like**.